# GetLocalResourceObject inside a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an ajax call that return a localized success message based on httpcontext,

```
        public ActionResult ReportViolation(string DiscussID) {

        Enumeration.Lang rLang = (Request.Cookies["MAKANI.Localization.CurrentUICulture"].Value.Equals("ar-EG")) ?
                        Enumeration.Lang.Arabic : Enumeration.Lang.English;


        if (Session["sId"] == null) return Json(false,
                                                HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", "msgDiscussViolationRegister").ToString(), 
                                                0, 
                                                null);
        else {
            long userId = AuthenticationModule.GetUserId(Convert.ToInt32(Session["sId"]));
            bool rReport = Discuss_BL.ReportViolation(Convert.ToInt32(DiscussID), userId);
            string rError = rReport 
                        ? HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", "msgDiscussViolationSuccess").ToString() 
                        : HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", "msgDiscussViolationExist").ToString();
            return Json(rReport, rError, 0, null);            
        }

    }
```

However, the resources always sends back the english version, is this the right way to use HttpContext from the controller?

--
Regards.

Yehia A.Salam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpContext` works as the **server** context, it will by default return the locale of the operating system ([`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx), to be precise). You need to read the users locale somehow - either by querying [`HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx), which may be empty, or by asking user for this information explicitly.

As [Scott Hanselman writes in his excellent article on globalization](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx), ASP.Net can actually set the worker thread culture (`Thread.Current.UICulture` and `Thread.Current.Culture`) for you, parsing the `Accept-Languages` HTTP header. Just add this snippet to your `web.config` for [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx):

```
<system.web>
  <globalization enableclientbasedculture="true" uiculture="auto" culture="auto">
...snip...</globalization></system.web>
```

Just be aware that user might have not setup his browser correctly, so he should always have the option to override the language settings.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Thread.Current.UICulture and Thread.Current.Culture values are not modified by ASP.NET and hence refer to the servers context - and thus, calls like `GetLocalResourceObject` will not react to the users browser settings.

However, ASP.NET can parse the Accept-Languages HTTP header, and set the Culture and UICulture values appropriately.

```
<system.web>
  <globalization enableclientbasedculture="true" culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
</system.web>
```

This article makes good reading: [Globalization, Internationalization and Localization in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)